# Background music in Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I want to have background music in my game which is coded in Swift 3. I tried a lot of tutorials and example codes but I can not find an implementation which is working in my Swift 3 code. The best example code I could find is this one:

```
lazy var backgroundMusic: AVAudioPlayer? = {
    guard let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "Music Title", withExtension: "mp3") else {
        return nil
    }

    do {
        let player = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: url)
        player.numberOfLoops = -1
        return player
    } catch {
        return nil
    }
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    backgroundMusic?.play()
}
```

I have put the music file in a separate folder called "Resources". I would be very happy if you can help me!

---

I changed the spaces in the file name with underscores but the problem is still given. 
By the way when I follow the translation hints from Xcode I get this code:

```
lazy var backgroundMusic: AVAudioPlayer? = {
    guard let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "Mining by Moonlight", withExtension: "mp3") else {
        return nil
    }

    do {
        let player = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: url)
        player.numberOfLoops = -1
        return player
    } catch {
        return nil
    }
}()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    backgroundMusic?.play()
}
```

After setting a breakpoint at `lazy var backgroundMusic` and stepping into the code, I attain the following result from the debugger:

> 0x1029097d8 <+760>: movq   0x69a9(%rip), %rcx        ; direct field offset for TabTab.ViewController.(backgroundMusic.storage in _98A37426C9C75C234890E1E239802C1D) : Swift.Optional>

Comment: And when you use the debugger to step through your code, you found.....?

Comment: Please don't ignore the error you cached. At very least log it.

Comment: When I use the debugger at the function entry I get this:

Comment: 0x1029097d8 <+760>: movq   0x69a9(%rip), %rcx        ; direct field offset for TabTab.ViewController.(backgroundMusic.storage in _98A37426C9C75C234890E1E239802C1D) : Swift.Optional<Swift.Optional<__ObjC.AVAudioPlayer>>

Comment: If you put the file at the root of the project not in a sub-folder, does it play? Depending how you added the audio files to the project (creating folder references or not), it might not find it in the main bundle without a more complete directory path.

Answer (score 2):

In swift 3

```
class MusicHelper {
static let sharedHelper = MusicHelper()
var audioPlayer: AVAudioPlayer?
func playBackgroundMusic() {
    let aSound = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: Bundle.main.path(forResource: "mario", ofType: "mp3")!)

    print(aSound)
    do {
        audioPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf:aSound as URL)
        audioPlayer!.numberOfLoops = -1
        audioPlayer!.prepareToPlay()
        audioPlayer!.play()
    } catch {
        print("Cannot play the file")
    }
}
```

}

and add this in viewdidLoad
**MusicHelper.sharedHelper.playBackgroundMusic()**

Answer (score 0):

solved the problem ALHAMDULELLAH only change in Xcode setting
[![go to setting page>>Capabilities>>Background>>modes>>Allow audio file]